# Can I redefine the ++ increment operator to make it behave like Haskell

Tags: custom-notation

In Haskell, joining two lists `l1` and `l2` is simply done with

```
l1 ++ l2
```

In Mathematica (infix notation), it's done with

```
l1 ~ Join ~ l2
```

Is it possible to achieve the same behavior in Mathematica?

The `++` operator is by default assigned to the increment operator, but I rarely use it, and actually use `~ Join ~` much more often.

I first tried to apply `Unprotect` and then `Remove` to `Increment`, but even after `++` will increment its argument.

Comment: you don't think the ++ operator is used internally?

Comment: Hm, I suppose that's a strong possibility. However, wouldn't it be possible with pattern matching to redefine it only when applied to lists? To overload it in some sense.

Comment: I wouldn't touch an internal function if I were you. You'd better ouch one of the undefined (and infix) symbols.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't thought of that. I'll keep with `~Join~` then, something like ⊕ wouldn't be supported by plain text source files. Thanks !

Comment: Those symbols would look like `\[CirclePlus]` and would survive their existence in Text files just fine.

Comment: No, it's not possible because `++` is a prefix or postfix operator.  You can't use it as infix.  Even if it were possible, due to how the language works, it would very likely break internal code.  So trying to do this is generally a bad idea.